# Dialogo persalizado sketchware

Tags: ide, dialog

Eu gostaria de saber como posso criar um diálogo personalizado? Será que alguém poderia me ajudar?

Eu já tentei muitos códigos mais não estão funcionando.

Comment: O que é sketchware?

Comment: Personalizado como? Que códigos você tentou?